# converting LaTex pdf into a powerpoint

Tags: pdf, powerpoint

I want to make a power point presentation with LaTex. I used the presentation template in sharelatex but the output was a `.pdf`. I want it to be ppt formate. is there any way I can get a direct `.ppt` from Latex?

Comment: In short? There is none. There might be some tool somewhere out there in the vast nothingness of space ... but, why do you want to convert a nice presentation done with `beamer` to a *smurfy* `ppt`-file?