# How to use pandoc to convert .tex file, containing a TikZ figure, to a .docx file?

Tags: tikz-pgf, conversion, pandoc

What I want to do is to convert a .tex file, containing several TikZ figures to a .docx-file using pandoc. I have tried to follow the pandoc documentation and to use lua filters to achieve this. Problem: whenever I use the lua filter, a file is generated that contains only the title of my .tex file and all the rest of the file is omitted. I do not see the TikZ figures either.

This is my input for pandoc in the commandline:

```
 pandoc --from latex+raw_tex --lua-filter=tikz.lua -s file.tex -o test.docx
```

My lua filter file (tikz.lua) is changed from the original filter suggested by [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html), on the basis of the advice given in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/431719/how-to-use-pandoc-to-derive-output-from-latex-and-tikz-to-a-docx-file). I have adopted the suggested changes there one-on-one to this file:

```
local function file_exists(name)
  local f = io.open(name, 'r')
  if f ~= nil then io.close(f); return true
  else return false end
end

function RawBlock(el)
  -- Don't alter element if it's not a tikzpicture environment
  if not el.text:match'^\\begin{tikzpicture}' then
    return nil
    -- Alternatively, parse the contained LaTeX now:
    -- return pandoc.read(el.text, 'latex').blocks
  end  
  local fname = pandoc.sha1(el.text) .. ".png"
  if not file_exists(fname) then
    tikz2image(el.text, fname)
  end
  return pandoc.Para({pandoc.Image({}, fname)})
end

--- Create a standalone LaTeX document which contains only the TikZ picture.
--- Convert to png via Imagemagick.
local function tikz2image(src, outfile)
  local tmp = os.tmpname()
  local tmpdir = string.match(tmp, "^(.*[\\/])") or "."
  local f = io.open(tmp .. ".tex", 'w')
  f:write("\\documentclass{standalone}\n")
  -- include all packages needed to compile your images
  f:write("\\usepackage{tikz}\n\\usepackage{stanli}\n")
  f:write("\\begin{document}\n")
  f:write(src)
  f:write("\n\\end{document}\n")
  f:close()
  os.execute("pdflatex -output-directory " .. tmpdir  .. " " .. tmp)
  os.execute("convert " .. tmp .. ".pdf " .. outfile)
  os.remove(tmp .. ".tex")
  os.remove(tmp .. ".pdf")
  os.remove(tmp .. ".log")
  os.remove(tmp .. ".aux")
end
```

pdflatex and pdf2svg are both installed, as well as ImageMagick.

In short, I should be good to go but something goes wrong and all I see is my title. Any advice would be really welcome!

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) -- (4,0);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

When rendering as a .pdf file in TexStudio, the TikZ figure shows up. When using pandoc, nothing happens.

Hopefully you can spot something I have missed!

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: I have now added the code of my tex files

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: Ah, thanks for reminding me of this. I think I have simplified the code now, without loss of crucial information. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Is your issue really related to including files and biblatex? And, more importantly, which pandoc filter are you using? You might want to post `tikz.lua`as well

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I have pruned the code even further to only focus on the lua filter problem. Hopefully this is better now!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The filter throws an error, because `convert` doesn't like to make a grey scale PNG. The solution is to add the option `-colorspace RGB`. In the end ImageMagick seems to have other issues too, so I suggest using `pdftoppm -png` form the [poppler tools](https://poppler.freedesktop.org) instead:

```
local function file_exists(name)
  local f = io.open(name, 'r')
  if f ~= nil then io.close(f); return true
  else return false end
end

--- Create a standalone LaTeX document which contains only the TikZ picture.
--- Convert to png via Imagemagick.
local function tikz2image(src, outfile)
  local tmp = os.tmpname()
  local tmpdir = string.match(tmp, "^(.*[\\/])") or "."
  -- local tmpdir = "."
  local f = io.open(tmp .. ".tex", 'w')
  f:write("\\documentclass{standalone}\n")
  -- include all packages needed to compile your images
  f:write("\\usepackage{tikz}\n\\usepackage{stanli}\n")
  f:write("\\begin{document}\n")
  f:write(src)
  f:write("\n\\end{document}\n")
  f:close()
  os.execute("pdflatex -output-directory " .. tmpdir  .. " " .. tmp)
  -- os.execute("convert " .. tmp .. ".pdf " .. "-colorspace RGB " .. outfile)
  os.execute("pdftoppm -png " .. tmp .. ".pdf " .. "> " .. outfile)
  os.remove(tmp .. ".tex")
  os.remove(tmp .. ".pdf")
  os.remove(tmp .. ".log")
  os.remove(tmp .. ".aux")
end

function RawBlock(el)
  -- Don't alter element if it's not a tikzpicture environment
  if not el.text:match'^\\begin{tikzpicture}' then
    return nil
    -- Alternatively, parse the contained LaTeX now:
    -- return pandoc.read(el.text, 'latex').blocks
  end  
  local fname = pandoc.sha1(el.text) .. ".png"
  if not file_exists(fname) then
    tikz2image(el.text, fname)
  end
  return pandoc.Para({pandoc.Image({}, fname)})
end
```

If you are using more complex tikz code, don't forget to add the used libraries and packages to the filter

---

You can also extend the [original filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#building-images-with-tikz) to cover `.docx`:

```
local system = require 'pandoc.system'

local tikz_doc_template = [[
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\nopagecolor
%s
\end{document}
]]

local function tikz2image(src, filetype, outfile)
  system.with_temporary_directory('tikz2image', function (tmpdir)
    system.with_working_directory(tmpdir, function()
      local f = io.open('tikz.tex', 'w')
      f:write(tikz_doc_template:format(src))
      f:close()
      os.execute('pdflatex tikz.tex')
      if filetype == 'pdf' then
        os.rename('tikz.pdf', outfile)
      elseif filetype == 'png' then
        os.execute("pdftoppm -png tikz.pdf > " .. outfile)
      else
        os.execute('pdf2svg tikz.pdf ' .. outfile)
      end
    end)
  end)
end

extension_for = {
  docx = 'png',
  html = 'svg',
  html4 = 'svg',
  html5 = 'svg',
  latex = 'pdf',
  beamer = 'pdf' }

local function file_exists(name)
  local f = io.open(name, 'r')
  if f ~= nil then
    io.close(f)
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end

local function starts_with(start, str)
  return str:sub(1, #start) == start
end


function RawBlock(el)
  if starts_with('\\begin{tikzpicture}', el.text) then
    local filetype = extension_for[FORMAT] or 'svg'
    local fname = system.get_working_directory() .. '/' ..
        pandoc.sha1(el.text) .. '.' .. filetype
    if not file_exists(fname) then
      tikz2image(el.text, filetype, fname)
    end
    return pandoc.Para({pandoc.Image({}, fname)})
  else
   return el
  end
end
```

---

Using it with the following document:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[fill] (1,2) circle (100pt);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

On the command line:

```
pandoc --from latex+raw_tex --lua-filter=tikz.lua -s file.tex -o test.docx
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, DG! Shamefully, I still get an error code `libpng warning: Image height is zero in IHDR
libpng error: Invalid IHDR dataError: /VMerror in --showpage--
VM status: 3 7465709 8808712
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: 2
GPL Ghostscript 9.26: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
convert: no images defined a7d104575554345e50033fe534bb432753f1c46f.png @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3285.
[WARNING] Could not fetch resource 'a7d104575554345e50033fe534bb432753f1c46f.png': PandocResourceNotFound "a7d104575554345e50033fe534bb432753f1c46f.png"`

Comment: By the way, this error popped up when I implemented the first of your suggestions. I did not fully understand how to use the second suggestion. Will the filter render a .docx file in your second alternative for the filter? What commands should I give to pandoc then? Excuse me for asking such basic questions.

Comment: Thanks. If I use the second option, the file runs without error message but there is no figure in my .docx file. For the first option, if I now tell tikz to `\draw[fill] (1,2) circle (100pt)`, I get the following error: `convert: no decode delegate for this image format' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/562.
convert: no images defined f50f0be0144d07fc26b680af5551537858520506.png @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3285.
[WARNING] Could not fetch resource f50f0be0144d07fc26b680af5551537858520506.png: PandocResourceNotFound "f50f0be0144d07fc26b680af5551537858520506.png"`

Comment: It seem like `convert` still has some trouble to correctly create the image, right?

Comment: Thank you for the reply and your effort. I am going to reinstall ImageMagick to see if the issue lies there... I will report it if I am successful.

Comment: I changed to code in order to use `pdftoppm`

Comment: Thank you so much, DG! This did the trick. I followed [this](https://gist.github.com/Dayjo/618794d4ff37bb82ddfb02c63b450a81) guide to install Poppler, which now creates the figures. So the problem was in ImageMagick in the end...

Comment: Just one more problem, shamefully. If I use more complex TeX files and more elaborate TikZ figures, I get the same issue as before: pandoc runs quickly, but only prints the title of the file without giving any error messages. In LaTeX, I use `\include{}` and write chapters in different files, could this be giving trouble? I have included all the information about the packages I use in the lua filter file, but still no success. Strange, as the filter now works on simpler files!

Comment: Ok, this is what's happening: For the filter to work, you need the option `+raw_tex`, which unfortunately turns off pandoc's capability to process `\include` statements. On way to solve this issue is by using a tool that *flattens* the latex source, i.e. [latexpand](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexpand): `latexpand file.tex | pandoc --from latex+raw_tex --lua-filter=tikz.lua -o test.docx`

Comment: Thanks, you're a genius. Using the first of your two suggestions above,this now works for simple files. However, more complex TikZ figures are not created. I use the TikZ package`arrows.meta`. You mention adding the packages I want to use to the lua filter. I cannot find the syntax to do so. Could you please illustrate what this would look like with the first option?

Comment: In the code is a comment reading: `-- include all packages needed to compile your images`. You need to add statements like `f:write("\\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}\n")`. Don't forget to escape special characters

Comment: That did it. I got it all working now. Amazing solutions, DG, I learned a lot about pandoc because of you.