Pandoc: Access violation in generated code when reading 0xffffffffffffffff
Reading the various answers on this site, I tried a way to convert a .tex file containing images generated with tikz into an editable format with MS Word. I followed the various instructions exactly, but the command prompt gives me this error:

Access violation in generated code when reading 0xffffffffffffffff
Attempting to reconstruct a stack trace...
Frame        Code address  * 0x1759bace70 0x7ff632aaef6e
C:\Users\Utente-XB\AppData\Local\Pandoc\pandoc.exe+0x2c9ef6e  *
0x1759bace78 0x61636f4c5c617461  * 0x1759bace80 0x735c706d65545c6c  *
0x1759bace88 0x302e777532  * 0x1759bace90 0x17c3e1f7028  *
0x1759baced0 0x7ff6344db02f
C:\Users\Utente-XB\AppData\Local\Pandoc\pandoc.exe+0x46cb02f  *
0x1759bacf30 0x7ff6344cb5f4
C:\Users\Utente-XB\AppData\Local\Pandoc\pandoc.exe+0x46bb5f4  *
0x1759bad050 0x7ff6344d29b8
C:\Users\Utente-XB\AppData\Local\Pandoc\pandoc.exe+0x46c29b8  *
0x1759bad090 0x7ff6344cb791
C:\Users\Utente-XB\AppData\Local\Pandoc\pandoc.exe+0x46bb791  *
0x1759bad200 0x7ff6344ca7f8
C:\Users\Utente-XB\AppData\Local\Pandoc\pandoc.exe+0x46ba7f8  *
0x1759bad260 0x7ff6344cbcf5
C:\Users\Utente-XB\AppData\Local\Pandoc\pandoc.exe+0x46bbcf5  *
0x1759bad2c0 0x7ff632aa926d
C:\Users\Utente-XB\AppData\Local\Pandoc\pandoc.exe+0x2c9926d  *
0x1759bad300 0x7ff6307dc531
C:\Users\Utente-XB\AppData\Local\Pandoc\pandoc.exe+0x9cc531  *
0x1759bad308 0x7ff630e40c57
C:\Users\Utente-XB\AppData\Local\Pandoc\pandoc.exe+0x1030c57  *
0x1759bad310 0x7ef4eb8261d0  * 0x1759bad318 0x9

I used this comand line: pandoc --from latex+raw_tex --lua-filter=tikz.lua -s test.tex -o test.docx
The tex code is as follows
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath,tcolorbox,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black]
  Some content and an equation $a=b$
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (4,4);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center} 

\end{document}

The Lua script is https://gist.github.com/gfacciol/4099a3e28a2a29611d1d3323071f7be0

Does a minimal document like \documentclass{article} \begin{document} zz \end{document} produce the same error? If so, does that minimal document also give an error for pandoc test_minimal.tex -o test_minimal.docx?

If you don't use the Lua script, do you still trigger the error? Try a simple Hello, world! document. If you still get the problem, check if pandoc is up to date and report a bug, if so.

@DaiBowen @cfr no, I get no error with pandoc test_minimal.tex -o test_minimal.docx. How can I check if pandoc is uo to date?

I get no error, but the text in the box doesn't appear, only the picture. Not on Windows, though.

@egreg I'm on Windows 10

The script here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/567791/29873 still works, not on windows though
