# pandoc markdown - drawing circuit diagrams using circuitikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I want to be able to use the commands in the `circuitikz` package for drawing circuit diagrams in my document which I am writing in Pandoc Markdown. I am familiar with inlining Latex math mode commands in pandoc but would it be possible to use the `circuitikz` environment and its associated commands as well ?

**Edit**: I am interested in PDF output only.

Comment: Are you interested in only PDF output from Pandoc, or conversion to other formats as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're only interested in PDF output from Pandoc, then you can just load the `ciruitikz` package in the `header-includes:` portion of your Markdown document as in the example below. If you want to do conversions to other formats, things are more complicated, but there are some questions on the site on how to include TikZ images into converted Pandoc documents. See e.g.

- [How to use PanDoc to derive output from LaTeX and TikZ to a DOCX file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/431719/2693)

```
--- 
header-includes: |
    \usepackage{circuitikz}
---
# A heading

Some text.


\begin{circuitikz}[american]
\draw (0,0) to[isource, l=$I_0$] (0,3) --
        (2,3)
   to[R=$R_1$] (2,0) -- (0,0);
   \draw (2,3) -- (4,3) to[R=$R_2$]
(4,0) -- (2,0); \end{circuitikz}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: sorry for the delayed response. Thanks a lot! this actually clarified a lot of things for me. I guess the question that I should have asked was : "How to use an arbitrary package within pandoc".

Comment: One thing you might want to be aware of is that with complex inline TeX, `pandoc` can sometimes get confused, and it might be better to use the `raw_attribute` extension rather than using the TeX inline like I've done here. See https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/4646 and https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-raw_attribute. I'd try it until it breaks. :)