# Converting a Beamer Presentation to Google Slides

Tags: beamer, conversion

Is it possible to convert a Beamer presentation to Google Slides format? I spent some time looking for a solution here and elsewhere without much luck, but perhaps I missed something.

Comment: I think this is on-topic for this forum. If this is a duplicate or can be improved in some way, kindly point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

It's not exactly doable because of a fundamental mismatch in LaTeX's design and what Google Slides (and other mainstream presentation software wants). [Export beamer slides to powerpoint/openoffice-impress/keynote editable format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21986/export-beamer-slides-to-powerpoint-openoffice-impress-keynote-editable-format) is probably your best best for a solution—I'm pretty sure that Google Slides can import powerpoint and the solutions at the linked question can at least get you part of the way there.