# Latex to word conversion is problematic with any way

Tags: conversion, latex-to-word, wiley-article

I have read other threads. However they cannot solve my problem. Anyone has any firm knowledge about how could we do that? I have a limited time and I dont know why my supervisor insists on word file.

Actually does anybody have any idea whether wiley accepts latex original file for the revision process? The editor asked for word file but I believe he forgot to mention latex. How come for initial submission they accept latex but for revision they mentioned just word?

I might get answer here g ask editor. Please do not answer like that since we could not ask directly from editor for many reasons.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Can you confirm that you were using the `wiley-article` documen class so far? If not, which other document class have you employed to date for the article (book?) in question?

Comment: Hi thanks https://authorservices.wiley.com/author-resources/Journal-Authors/Prepare/new-journal-design.html. Used latest version of template

Comment: Normally they should accept latex in revised version also. I dont know why my supervisor do not accept to ask editor once to be ensured. If they accept latex in initial submission why they should not accept in revised version?

Comment: Look, there's no magic solution. If there were, the person would have posted it in one of the existing questions and get upvotes already. → [conversion - Workflow for converting LaTeX into Open Office / MS Word Format - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4145/workflow-for-converting-latex-into-open-office-ms-word-format)

Comment: You or one of your co-authors will eventually have to drum up the courage to defy your adviser and go ask the editor for a clarification/ruling on whether it's ok to submit the revised manuscript in LaTeX instead of in Word.

Comment: Depending of the article contents, formats  and converters, your mileage exporting formats may vary a lot, but you'll always pay a toll. In general, as more rich is the format  that the converter try to maintain, the more junk you'll take. Therefore,  my general approach  is first lost all non essential fat,  converting to the simplest format  (markdown)  and then to the final format. It is always better having to deal with some lost format as margins, that having to clean a too rich format.

Comment: You could also fool the supervisor (guy?) .... Just compile your LaTeX file to PDF, the change the extension `pdf`  to `docx`  and submit that file to the supervisor. Modern Word versions open `pdf`'s, but wonder whether the document can be edited by Word ... Would (s)he be smart enough to discover that?? ;-P But best to contact Wiley yourself and bypass the supervisor. It's your article and credits, not his/hers.

Comment: Come one! How fool. Obviously the word is deformated1

Comment: Thanks all.........................

Comment: Take a look at *pandoc* ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/633247/262081) an e.g. from ‘.tex’ to PPTX but completely transposable for DOCX).