# Beamer-Generated slides to PPT?

Tags: beamer, conversion

I like creating slides in Beamer.  My supervisor doesn't.  He wants me to "generate or convert [the set I did for a conference] to PowerPoint."  I've tried different online and offline products like `Okto all to PowerPoint', TotalPDFConverter, and free-pdf-to-ppt-converter, but none of them quite cut it.

Most will screw up the text and/or the graphics, or simply convert the whole thing into a number of (low-resolution) bitmaps which are included in a PPT.  The best results I get with pdf2picture, which can convert PDFs into WMF or EWMF files which can be inserted into PPT slides.  When converting text to curves, most of the graphics look ok, however transparency doesn't seem to be handled correctly and it's still a lot of work inserting one WMF after another.

It says [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9462/how-should-i-convert-my-beamer-slides-to-powerpoint-according-to-these-odd-speci) that going through Keynote seems to work, but I'm already using PPT in a VM inside Linux---bringing in another OS would really be overkill.

Does anyone have any other hints?  The result should look like the original PDF and it should be editable, but it's alright if for example text is converted to curves or so.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) No need to add thanks or sign. This is not rude, we just try keeping questions more focussed that way.

Comment: BTW +1: I'd really like to know the answer to that one. Having 3 OS on your system, just to convert a presentation to %@*! PPT really hurts...

Comment: I guess one of the questions would be: what does your supervisor intend to do with your presentation? just include a selection of slides from it onto his? or actually use your presentation and modify some of the content? For the first use case, generating high quality graphics from the slides should be enough. The second one is trickier as some things may not have a one to one equivalent between the two format.

Comment: The slides would have to be editable enough so graphics can be moved around.  However, the text does not have to be actual text as long as it can be deleted and replaced individually, i.e. without having to re-design the whole slide.

Comment: May not be optimal, but if your institution has a licence for Adobe Acrobat Standard (or above), you can convert pdf to word within it directly (it seems, from the specs, that it can convert from pdf to work or excel but not powerpoint for some reason but I haven't got a copy so I cannot check). It then may not be too much work for your supervisor to do something with the MS Word output.

Comment: For the editing by supervisor part, here is the best agreement I found: print to paper, your reviewer/supervisor marks whatever edits he wants with a pen and you modify the slides accordingly. It's a win-win: fastest for him, best quality for you.

Comment: see also here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21986/export-beamer-slides-to-powerpoint-openoffice-impress-keynote-editable-format

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Howdy this is a half automatic answer.

1. run `htlatex yourfile.tex "html,word" "-coo"` to extract some of the text
2. Erase all the text wich should be editable.
3. make hi-res Pictures out of the pdf e.g. with this script:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   read name
   pdftk $name burst
   convert -density 288 pg_000*.pdf +adjoin -quality 100 -size 3000x4000    pg.jpg
   ```

   This is not editable but can be included into PP.
4. bring those pictures in the background of yout PP file.
5. reinsert the text using PP (generated in step 0.).

Comment: To clarify: the idea is to use htlatex to extract formatted text which can be copied to PPT where editable text is needed, right?  I would probably clear the text in the images from step 3 instead of in the tex file, to preserve spacing, but otherwise that's a good idea.  I'm holding out for a more automatic solution, but will accept this if none comes up.

Comment: Yes. It´s much easier to copy html into any Office Product than from tex or pdf. In my experience pp understands html quite well (afaik word even knows a thing 'call save as html')

Answer (score 14):

This is an incomplete solution, but [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) imports PDF to presentation, preserving text (mostly) and layout (sort of). I've used it to convert simple beamer presentations to office.

1. Open an empty Libreoffice impress file
2. Go to the menu `File->Open...` and select the pdf file
3. Save as .pptx
4. Enjoy :D

Comment: When I open a PDF with LibreOffice, it gets me into LibreOffice Draw which does not let me save as PPT.

Comment: This was a couple of versions ago, but I know that you used to be able to open LibreOffice's presentation softwared and import (not open) a pdf.

Comment: @vikas The workflow you suggested in your edit can be simplified by opening the pdf directly from within impress

Comment: This is done in one command line (PDF to PPT or OPD, etc.): `soffice --infilter=impress_pdf_import --convert-to ppt filetoconvert.pdf` (details [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/633247/262081), this linked answer also deals with some conversion output issues using *LibreOffice* or *soffice* for PDF to PPT conversion)

Comment: @gerrit Yes, in latest versions of Impress (e.g. v7.3.0.3 30(Build:3)), opening a PDF automatically redirect to Draw. And after no way to save/export as ODP or PPT **BUT** you can "force" Impress to open the PDF by selecting this file type in the open file screen `Ctrl-o`: "PDF – Portable Document Format (Impress) (*.pdf)" [details here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1365457)

Answer (score 8):

Here (https://github.com/martinGithub/beamer2pptx) is a small python script that extracts elements of the beamer using regular expressions, creates an image for each equation and generates a powerpoint with the same number of slide with the equations and the images. It does not keep the layout, but it can help as a first step before manual edition of the resulting powerpoint.