# Convert beamer presentation to (non-editable) powerpoint

Tags: beamer, conversion, powerpoint

I'm looking for a way to automatically convert my beamer slides to powerpoint format (or something else LibreOffice Impress can read).

I found some ideas [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61140/beamer-generated-slides-to-ppt) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9462/how-should-i-convert-my-beamer-slides-to-powerpoint-according-to-these-odd-speci), but they are too complicated to automatically generate a ppt copy every time I change my beamer presentation. I'm thinking the goal should be simpler than what the aforementioned links refer to, as my ppt presentation doesn't have to be editable, or doesn't have any strange specifications.

Libreoffice can read the pdf file, but opens it in Draw, and I see no option to convert it into a presentation. Equally, the formatting isn't respected, so lines run of slides in the Draw-imported images, making me thing that there is no way of making this process automatic using LibreOffice.

I guess some workflow would be :

1. extract each pdf slide as an image
2. import each of these images as full-screen illustrations in ppt or
   odp

Any suggestion ?

Comment: No there are no other options. Still the questions you have linked are the only ways. I think this question is still a duplicate because I don't see the complication.

Comment: The complication is that I can't make a script out of the solutions mentioned; they need human supervision. I can `pdftoppm` my beamer presentation, and import each image manually in LibreOffice Impress, adjusting its size, but this is not useable for presentations having several tens or hundreds of slides.

Comment: When I had a lot of (100+) automatically generated figures to add to a PP presentation, I used the `Insert->PhotoAlbum` tool available in the newer versions of PowerPoint. You can add images in bulk. There is an option called `fit images to slide` which will fill the slide with the figure. Use `imagemagick` to `convert` your pdf to sequentially numbered `png`s or `jpg`s. http://www.gcflearnfree.org/powerpoint2010/creating-photo-albums-in-powerpoint  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-photo-album-2a66a94e-4279-4aad-b829-7277fd111cea

Comment: @AJN : Great idea, this also works in Libreoffice Impress ! `Insert -> Image -> Photo Album`. I didn't know it would be this simple, but if you post this comment as an anwer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved in comments

Comment: i think not so much off-topic but duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21986/13173 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/6534271/54964