# Produce a pptx or keynote file from a beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, pdf, conversion, powerpoint

I'm giving a presentation at a venue with a production staff.  Although they claim not to need to edit or re-brand my slides, they have asked me to supply the slides in advance using either powerpoint or keynote format, not PDF.

Unfortunately, I user beamer for all of my presentations, and use linux on my desktop and all of my machines.  I'm comfortable using command-line tools like `qpdf` or the LaTeX pdfpages package to break my presentation up into individual pages.  I also have access to libreoffice and google slides, but don't know how to use them.  I can't run powerpoint or keynote.

I'm wondering what a good way would be to convert my presentation.  Worst-case, I could break it up into pages and import each PDF into a slide using libreoffice or google slides, then export that as pptx, though that seems kind of painful.  (In typical beamer fashion, each animation step is its own page in the PDF.)  I'd much rather have something I could include in my Makefile to generate a pptx, or failing that a one-shot way of converting the pdf to pptx.

My question, then:  What's a relatively painless way to create a high-quality pptx or keynote file given a beamer presentation or its resulting pdf/eps/dvi?  I like open-source stuff, but in this instance would also settle for proprietary web services.  There's nothing confidential in the presentation.

**update** It was ambiguous, but for my use case I do not want the PPT to be editable.  It is my presentation, and I just want to have my slides projected.  Hence, while there are other questions with answers about creating editable powerpoint, my question was about creating a powerpoint that will project as close as possible to what I had.  The best answer I found is [pdf2pptx](https://github.com/ashafaei/pdf2pptx), which is close but not perfect.  Some symbols like `$\Longrightarrow$` don't render perfectly, but for the most part it is good enough.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9462/161015

Comment: pdftokeynote sounds intriguing, but A) only works on Mac, and B) might produce an old version of keynote.  Worst case I might have a colleague with a MacOX laptop who could run this, but I would much prefer something I can do myself.

Comment: There is [this on-line service](https://www.zamzar.com/convert/pdf-to-pptx/)

Comment: I use [pdf2pptx](https://github.com/ashafaei/pdf2pptx), and it is very convenient. But it is not editable since the beamer is converted to high-quality images.

Comment: Take look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/633247/262081) which presents several methods for PDF to non editable Power Point (and also editable).